# Background image for Libre Office Writer heading not working

Tags: images, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

## My objective:

I'm applying background image to both Heading 1 and Heading 2 in a Libre Office Writer document.

## My problem:

The behaviour of the background image for Heading 2 is inconsistent with that of Heading 1. Heading 2 appears to left align unlike Heading 1, which correctly left aligns.

[image]

Both background images are 2250px x 250px. The only difference is graphical in that the width of the coloured area (grey) of Heading 2 is 250px less wide:

[image]

## What I've tried:

I've created a test image for Heading 2 in which the coloured area (grey) is not 250px less wide. The result is that the background image is correctly right aligning:

[image]

For comparison, these are the three images I'm using:

[image]

## My question:

Why is this inconsistency occurring and how do I fix it?

I'm embedding the three individual images if anyone wishes to test on their end:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Part A: Via Settings:

Heading 2 > Edit Style > Area > Bitmap:

1. Set style to "custom".
2. Check scale checkbox.
3. Set width and height both to 100%.

Steps must be performed in this order because setting width and height to 100% automatically and undesirably sets style to "original".

This works with the exception that graphical distortion occurs. I.e. Diagonal edge of graphics is not longer 45 degrees.

## Part B: Via Graphics:

The workaround to the product of part A is to redraw the background images at the correct aspect ratio.

1. Screen-capture document. Paste into Photoshop and measure dimensions of headings in pixels.
2. Create heading graphics at three times the size of the measured dimensions.
3. Incorporate graphics into document using steps of part A.

Note: Each time the style editor is opened, the settings for the background image will reset. This is a known glitch with Libre Office.

## Successful End Result:

[image]

Source: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/150285/background-image-for-writer-heading-not-working/